# how come it's ok for customView extends constraintLayout but inflates linear layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, layout-inflater

say i have a custom android view:

```
public class myView extends ConstraintLayout {
```

and in its ctor I call:

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.header, this, true);
```

I see `inflate` returns a `View`, but the calling code doesn't use it at all. so how does it takes an affect?

In addition what would happen if the customView inherits from constraintLayout but the inflated xml is linear layout

why would it work?

Comment: inflate returns a view and that is top or parent layout of the xml. On the other hand you are using custom view inside that parent layout. When you inflat a layout then you are able to access child layout and that can be any of the view inside main layout view group.

Comment: but no one uses this returned view

Comment: this view is always used. if not why someone inflates the xml file?

Comment: it is used, but nobody saves the returned view object from the inflater.